# Custom resizable flexbox views using vanilla JavaScript jumps on mousedown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make each of the 4 view containers resizable. I want it to be similar to Codepen. I'm start with having the width of V1 and V2 be resizable. The blue border between the view is the handle. When I put the mousedown on the handle V2's width suddenly and noticeably increases in size. **Why is this happening?**

The idea behind my implementation is to calculate the difference between mouse down and mouse up x-cordinate positions, then add this calculated difference to the width (or technically flex-basis) of the container.

[Heres my codepen.](http://codepen.io/danielyaa5/pen/gPyKPw) Thanks for any help.

## HTML

```
<div id="views-cntnr">
  <div id="r1" class="view-row">
    <div id="v1" class="view">
      <div class="v-header">
        <button class="vh-btn v-settings"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></button>
        <span class="v-title">R-Theta</span>
        <button class="vh-btn v-close"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="handle" id="r1-l-r">
    </div>
    <div id="v2" class="view">
      <div class="v-header">
        <button class="vh-btn v-settings"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></button>
        <span class="v-title">Cartesian</span>
        <button class="vh-btn v-close"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="r2" class="view-row">
    <div id="v3" class="view">
      <div class="v-header">
        <button class="vh-btn v-settings"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></button>
        <span class="v-title">Longitudinal</span>
        <button class="vh-btn v-close"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="r3" class="view-row">
    <div id="v4" class="view">
      <div class="v-header">
        <span class="v-title">Console</span>
        <button class="vh-btn v-close"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

/* VIEWS */



/* VIEW HEADERS */

.v-header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px;
  border-bottom: #bfbfbf 1px solid;
  background-color: #1a1b1c;
  color: #ccc;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.v-title {
  position: relative;
  left: 35px;
}

#v4 .v-title {
  left: 6px;
}


/*VIEW BTNS */

.vh-btn {
  padding: 2px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: #343436;
  color: white;
  border: black 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
}

.vh-btn:hover {
  background-color: #4d4d50;
}

.v-settings {
  left: 6px;
}

.v-close {
  right: 5px;
}


/* view btns */


/* view headers */

#views-cntnr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

/* HANDLES */

#r1-l-r {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  width: 10px
}

/* handles */

/* ROWS */


/* ROW 1 */

#r1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 4;
}

#r1 .view {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: #bfbfbf 1px solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
}

#r1 .view:last-child {
  border-left: none;
}


/* row 1 */


/* ROW 2 */

#r2 .view {
  border: #bfbfbf 1px solid;
  border-top: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#r2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 3;
}


/* row 2 */


/* ROW 3 */

#r3 .view {
  border: #bfbfbf 1px solid;
  border-top: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#r3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 2;
}


/* row 3 */


/* rows */


/* views */
```

### JS

```
var mouseStartPosition = {};
var v1StartWidth;

var v1 = document.getElementById('v1');
var v2 = document.getElementById('v2');
var r1_lr_handle = document.getElementById('r1-l-r');

r1_lr_handle.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedownR1RL);

function mousedownR1RL(e) {
  // get v1 width
  v1StartWidth = v1.offsetWidth;
  // get mouse position
  mouseStartPosition.x = e.pageX;
  mouseStartPosition.y = e.pageY;

  console.log('start... x:', mouseStartPosition.x, 'y:', mouseStartPosition.y);

  // add listeners for mousemove, mouseup
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
}

function mousemove(e) {
  console.log('mouse move... x:', e.pageX, 'y:', e.pageY);
  var diff = mouseStartPosition.x - e.pageX;
  v2.style.flexBasis = v1StartWidth + diff + 'px';
}

function mouseup(e) {
  window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
  window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update the size of two boxes. The browser try to grow the non-updated box when you do update only one. It work with this little update on JS.

```
var mouseStartPosition = {};
var v1StartWidth;
var v2StartWidth;

var v1 = document.getElementById('v1');
var v2 = document.getElementById('v2');
var r1_lr_handle = document.getElementById('r1-l-r');

r1_lr_handle.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedownR1RL);

function mousedownR1RL(e) {
  // get v1 width
  v1StartWidth = v1.offsetWidth;
  v2StartWidth = v2.offsetWidth;
  // get mouse position
  mouseStartPosition.x = e.pageX;
  mouseStartPosition.y = e.pageY;

  console.log('start... x:', mouseStartPosition.x, 'y:', mouseStartPosition.y);

  // add listeners for mousemove, mouseup
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
}

function mousemove(e) {
  // console.log('mouse move... x:', e.pageX, 'y:', e.pageY);
  var diff = mouseStartPosition.x - e.pageX;
    v1.style.flexBasis = v1StartWidth + -1*diff + 'px';
    v2.style.flexBasis = v2StartWidth + diff + 'px';
}

function mouseup(e) {
  window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
  window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
}
```

Comment: mind taking a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489302/resizable-function-for-flexbox-row-height-using-vanilla-javascript-causes-view-i