# Flexbox rows that maintain original height ratio on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexbox

My main goal with my project is to have resizable flexbox div views. I have working resizable columns for `#v1` and `#v2`. I also have rows that can be resized, the handles are the blue part. Now Im working on have the height of the rows maintain their height ratio when the window height changes. **Whats wrong with my approach/ why isnt it working as expected?**

[Heres the codepen I'm working in.](http://codepen.io/danielyaa5/pen/rxgoyy?editors=1011)

My approach: Use jQuery `$(window).onResize()` . Measure that difference between the last recorded height and the current new height and calculate the difference. Pass this difference to a function called `resizeRows` which takes the difference calculated as a parameter. `resizeRows` then splits the difference in and adds it amongst the 3 rows. **Logic can be found at the bottom of JS code posted**.

Issues: Strange behavior. Rows dont appear to maintain their original height ratios.

### HTML

```
<div id="views-cntnr">
  <div id="r1" class="view-row">
    <div id="v1" class="view">
      <div class="v-header">
        <button class="vh-btn v-settings"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></button>
        <span class="v-title">R-Theta</span>
        <button class="vh-btn v-close"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-handle" id="r1-l-r">
    </div>
    <div id="v2" class="view">
      <div class="v-header">
        <button class="vh-btn v-settings"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></button>
        <span class="v-title">Cartesian</span>
        <button class="vh-btn v-close"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="r1-r2-u-d" class="row-handle"></div>
  <div id="r2" class="view-row">
    <div id="v3" class="view">
      <div class="v-header">
        <button class="vh-btn v-settings"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></button>
        <span class="v-title">Longitudinal</span>
        <button class="vh-btn v-close"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-handle" id="r2-r3-u-d">
  </div>
  <div id="r3" class="view-row">
    <div id="v4" class="view">
      <div class="v-header">
        <span class="v-title">Console</span>
        <button class="vh-btn v-close"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
var mouseStartPosition = {};
var v1StartWidth, v2StartWidth, r1StartHeight, r2StartHeight, r3StartHeight;

var views_cntnr = document.getElementById('views-cntnr');
var views_cntnr_height = views_cntnr.offsetHeight;

// rows
var r1 = document.getElementById('r1');
var r2 = document.getElementById('r2');
var r3 = document.getElementById('r3');

// views
var v1 = document.getElementById('v1');
var v2 = document.getElementById('v2');

// handles
var r1_lr_handle = document.getElementById('r1-l-r');
var r1_r2_ud = document.getElementById('r1-r2-u-d');
var r2_r3_ud = document.getElementById('r2-r3-u-d');

r1_lr_handle.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedownR1LR);
r1_r2_ud.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedownR1R2UD);
r2_r3_ud.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedownR2R3UD);

var init_r1_ratio = 0.4;
var init_r2_ratio = 0.3;
var init_r3_ratio = 0.3;

initRowHeights();
function initRowHeights() {
  console.log(views_cntnr_height);
  r1.style.flexBasis = views_cntnr_height*init_r1_ratio + 'px';
  r2.style.flexBasis = views_cntnr_height*init_r2_ratio + 'px';
  r3.style.flexBasis = views_cntnr_height*init_r3_ratio + 'px';
}

/* V1 V2 WIDTH RESIZE */
function mousedownR1LR(e) {
  // get v1 width
  v1StartWidth = v1.offsetWidth;
  v2StartWidth = v2.offsetWidth;
  // get mouse position
  mouseStartPosition.x = e.pageX;
  mouseStartPosition.y = e.pageY;

  // add listeners for mousemove, mouseup
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveR1LR);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseupR1LR);
}

function mousemoveR1LR(e) {
  var diff = mouseStartPosition.x - e.pageX;
  v1.style.flexBasis = v1StartWidth + -1 * diff + 'px';
  v2.style.flexBasis = v2StartWidth + diff + 'px';
}

function mouseupR1LR(e) {
  window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveR1LR);
  window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseupR1LR);
}

/* v1 v2 width resize */

/* R1 R2 HEIGHT RESIZE */
function mousedownR1R2UD(e) {
  // get R1 R2 height
  r1StartHeight = r1.offsetHeight;
  r2StartHeight = r2.offsetHeight;

  // get mouse position
  mouseStartPosition.x = e.pageX;
  mouseStartPosition.y = e.pageY;

  // add listeners for mousemove, mouseup
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveR1R2UD);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseupR1R2UD);
}

function mousemoveR1R2UD(e) {
  var diff = mouseStartPosition.y - e.pageY;
  r1.style.flexBasis = r1StartHeight + -1 * diff + 'px';
  r2.style.flexBasis = r2StartHeight + 1 * diff + 'px';
}

function mouseupR1R2UD(e) {
  window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveR1R2UD);
  window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseupR1R2UD);
}

/* r1 r2 height resize */

/* R2 R3 HEIGHT RESIZE */
function mousedownR2R3UD(e) {
  // get R2 R3 height
  r2StartHeight = r2.offsetHeight;
  r3StartHeight = r3.offsetHeight;

  // get mouse position
  mouseStartPosition.x = e.pageX;
  mouseStartPosition.y = e.pageY;

  // add listeners for mousemove, mouseup
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveR2R3UD);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseupR2R3UD);
}

function mousemoveR2R3UD(e) {
  var diff = mouseStartPosition.y - e.pageY;
  r2.style.flexBasis = r2StartHeight + -1 * diff + 'px';
}

function mouseupR2R3UD(e) {
  window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveR2R3UD);
  window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseupR2R3UD);
}

/* r2 r3 height resize */

function resizeRows(pixels) {
  var increase = pixels/3;
  r1.style.flexBasis = parseInt(r1.style.flexBasis) + increase + 'px';
  r2.style.flexBasis = parseInt(r2.style.flexBasis) + increase + 'px';
  r3.style.flexBasis = parseInt(r3.style.flexBasis) + increase + 'px';

};

$(window).resize(function() {
  var new_views_cntnr_height = views_cntnr.offsetHeight;
  var height_change = new_views_cntnr_height - views_cntnr_height;
  views_cntnr_height = new_views_cntnr_height;

  resizeRows(height_change);
});

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

/* VIEWS */



/* VIEW HEADERS */

.v-header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px;
  border-bottom: #bfbfbf 1px solid;
  background-color: #1a1b1c;
  color: #ccc;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.v-title {
  position: relative;
  left: 35px;
}

#v4 .v-title {
  left: 6px;
}


/*VIEW BTNS */

.vh-btn {
  padding: 2px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: #343436;
  color: white;
  border: black 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
}

.vh-btn:hover {
  background-color: #4d4d50;
}

.v-settings {
  left: 6px;
}

.v-close {
  right: 5px;
}


/* view btns */


/* view headers */

#views-cntnr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

/* HANDLES */

#r1-l-r {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  width: 6px;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.row-handle {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  height: 6px;
  cursor: row-resize;
}

/* handles */

/* ROWS */


/* ROW 1 */

#r1 {
  display: flex;
}

#r1 .view {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: #bfbfbf 1px solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
}

#r1 .view:last-child {
  border-left: none;
}


/* row 1 */


/* ROW 2 */

#r2 .view {
  border: #bfbfbf 1px solid;
  border-top: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#r2 {
  display: flex;
}


/* row 2 */


/* ROW 3 */

#r3 .view {
  border: #bfbfbf 1px solid;
  border-top: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#r3 {
  display: flex;
}


/* row 3 */


/* rows */


/* views */
```

Comment: FYI your codepen link returns a 404 error and you have CSS mixed in with your JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish the effect fairly simply - [codepen here.](http://codepen.io/alflenniken/pen/KzYMWW)

Make sure you assign a flex-basis to each row, altering it with javascript to accomplish the dragging effect. On window resize the elements will fit themselves to the container automatically, so you don't need to fuss with window on resize.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="row" id="row-1">
    <div class="handle"></div>
    <div class="row-header"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="row-2">
    <div class="handle"></div>
    <div class="row-header"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="row-3">
    <div class="handle"></div>
    <div class="row-header"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: white;
  height: 100vh;
}
.row {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  border: 4px solid #333;
  border-top: none;
}
.handle {
  height: 15px;
  background: lightblue;
  cursor: move;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('.row').mousedown(function(event){
    // They have dragged a row
    // Adjust the flex-basis of the previous row
    // Since index is 0 based and the rows are 1 based, use the index with the row to select the previous one

    var this_index = $(this).index()
    var selected_id = (this_index == 0) ? selected_id = '' : selected_id = '#row-' + this_index

    // Get starting flex-basis as int
    var starting_basis = $(selected_id).css('flex-basis')
    starting_basis = starting_basis.substr(0, starting_basis.length - 2)
    starting_basis = Number(starting_basis)

    var start_y = event.pageY

    $(document).mousemove(function(event){
      // Change flex basis as mouse moves
      y_pos = event.pageY - start_y

      var new_flex_basis = starting_basis + y_pos
      new_flex_basis += 'px'

      $(selected_id).css('flex-basis', new_flex_basis)
    })
  })

  $(document).mouseup(function(){
    $(document).off('mousemove')
  })
})
```